# Fast binning of geographical data with negative values

Tags: scipy.stats

Trying to bin some geolocated data using scipy `stats.binned_statisc_2d` but it seems there cannot exist any negative values in the data. Is there a way to do this accurately and fast?

```
import numpy as np

ilats = np.linspace(90,-90, 4000)
ilons = np.linspace(-180, 179.955, 8000)
values = np.array([17,-14, -7,-8,-11,-8,-7,-8,-10,-5,-3,
         -12,-5, -6,21,30, 2, 4,-8, 6, 4, 7,
         3,-6,-13, 21, 4, 5,11,-6, 8,-5,-6,
         9,8,-8, -2,-16,-5,-5,-9,-4,-6,33,
         -8,-5,-14,-8,-11,21,24,-7,-13,12,-6,
         5,7,8,-3,-3,-4, 4, 9,-3, 9,-11,
         -8,6,4, 8,-6,-6,-4,-3, 4, 5,11,
         -3,-6,-4,-8,-4,12,-9,-8,15,-10,-5,
         -4,12,5,-4, 4, 7,-13, 5,-4,-4,-5,
         -8,-10,-9,-7.])
lats = np.array([  6.7427,  42.7027,  42.6963,  10.3688,  37.5713,  37.5798,
       -12.1563,  42.7127,  41.7457,  37.8122,  37.66  ,  41.7456,
       41.7457,  38.4462,   8.5418, -12.7309, -10.9395, -10.9464,
       38.0641, -10.9507, -12.7316, -10.9313, -12.7235,  37.6469,
       38.1234,  20.3964, -12.0847, -12.0844,  10.3794,  38.1302,
       10.3627,  38.1582,  38.1463,  22.6466,  20.4246,  38.1401,
       -36.6505,  38.2352,  37.8795,  40.2281,  37.8125,  42.323 ,
       37.8775,   9.3717,  38.732 ,  38.7202,  38.2688,  38.9148,
       38.9414,  -4.8618,  -4.8525,  39.0108,  38.8187,  -6.5067,
       38.009 ,  -6.5174,  -6.5101,  -6.51  ,  37.7243,  37.7512,
       37.7215,  -6.4902,  -6.5113,  37.5409,   1.9481,  37.6398,
       -6.5073,  37.8037, -11.133 ,   9.0896,  38.177 ,   9.089 ,
       37.8708,  38.3848,  -3.553 ,   9.4345,  -3.5343,  -3.5769,
       37.6847,  37.6045,  37.8857,  38.32  ,   8.1673,  37.8822,
       37.9113,   8.6278,  37.5652,  37.8236,  37.8593,   8.6219,
       -3.5614,  37.924 ,  37.7845,  37.8436,  37.8666,  37.6804,
       37.639 ,  40.7691,  40.7744,  37.8029,  42.9793,   8.207 ,
       39.302 ])

lons = np.array([ 60.8964, -96.1017, -96.1049,  71.595 , -97.0008, -97.0126,
       57.4887, -96.109 , -95.1058, -97.1088, -96.6413, -95.1054,
       -95.1062, -95.2395,  58.3938, -73.7145, -70.626 , -70.5864,  
       -95.5678, -70.5914, -73.7525, -70.6048, -73.753 , -96.7662,
       -95.504 , 100.3965, -70.7921, -70.7905,  71.5499, -95.4816,
       71.5457, -95.326 , -95.3355,  96.8339, 100.2684, -95.8697,
       39.1031, -95.4456, -96.3814, -94.5726, -96.3782, -95.4554,
       -96.3797, -66.7449, -95.1513, -95.1465, -95.0972, -95.2498,
       -95.2054,  84.2004,  84.21  , -94.5695, -94.9174, 114.0945, 
       -95.942 , 114.0592, 114.0956, 114.0873, -96.4689, -96.4599,
       -96.463 , 114.0741, 114.0975, -96.582 , 117.2901, -96.572 ,
       114.0561, -96.5539, -74.9417,  71.3391, -95.4253,  71.2452,
       -96.5511, -95.065 , 107.5832,  71.3906, 107.6005, 107.4975,
       -96.9722, -96.9307, -96.2627, -95.1745,  72.5249, -96.2632,
       -96.3324,  57.9562, -96.9309, -96.5123, -96.589 ,  57.9627,
       107.6405, -96.2711, -96.5737, -96.2344, -96.2099, -96.5062,
       -96.5248, -94.8421, -94.8522, -96.5873, -97.1523,  72.4707,
       -95.0489])

ret = stats.binned_statistic_2d(lons, lats, values, 'count', bins=[ilons, ilats])
```

Trying to examine the ungridded data, `values` by gridding them on a coarse grid (ilats, ilons) and plotting the counts first case and mean later on. But the above results produce:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [52], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 ret = stats.binned_statistic_2d(lons, lats, ka, 'count', bins=[ilons, ilats])

File ~/anaconda3/envs/synrad/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy-1.9.3-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/scipy/stats/_binned_statistic.py:352, in binned_statistic_2d(x, y, values, statistic, bins, range, expand_binnumbers)
    349     xedges = yedges = np.asarray(bins, float)
    350     bins = [xedges, yedges]
--> 352 medians, edges, binnumbers = binned_statistic_dd(
    353     [x, y], values, statistic, bins, range,
    354     expand_binnumbers=expand_binnumbers)
    356 return BinnedStatistic2dResult(medians, edges[0], edges[1], binnumbers)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/synrad/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy-1.9.3-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/scipy/stats/_binned_statistic.py:571, in binned_statistic_dd(sample, values, statistic, bins, range, expand_binnumbers, binned_statistic_result)
    569 if binned_statistic_result is None:
    570     nbin, edges, dedges = _bin_edges(sample, bins, range)
--> 571     binnumbers = _bin_numbers(sample, nbin, edges, dedges)
    572 else:
    573     edges = binned_statistic_result.bin_edges

File ~/anaconda3/envs/synrad/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy-1.9.3-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/scipy/stats/_binned_statistic.py:752, in _bin_numbers(sample, nbin, edges, dedges)
    750 if dedges_min == 0:
    751     raise ValueError('The smallest edge difference is numerically 0.')
-->** 752 decimal = int(-np.log10(dedges_min)) + 6**
    753 # Find which points are on the rightmost edge.
    754 on_edge = np.where((sample[:, i] >= edges[i][-1]) &
    755                    (np.around(sample[:, i], decimal) ==
    756                     np.around(edges[i][-1], decimal)))[0]

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

It looks like there is a log operation and I don't see a way around it.

Comment: What's your reason for ordering `ilats` from positive to negative? If replaced with `np.linspace(-90, 90, 4000)`, the code runs error-free.

Comment: @AlexK It was to keep the north pole up. But this is not significant. Thanks for point it out. This works quite nicely now.

Comment: @AlexK Do you have an example of how to pass a function to `stats.binned_statisc_2d` in order to do the stats in each bin?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you need, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73777493/9987623) is a recent post where I helped someone put together a custom function.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think it was that simple. I was thinking of using a lambda, but this example is perfect!